# Jquery inside Ajax loaded page does not work

Tags: ajax, jquery

When I use

```
$('body').html(data1)
```

or

```
$('html').html(data1)
```

in AJAX, then any HTML tag or jQuery function does not work on the loaded page.

```
$.ajax({
    type:"GET",
    dataType: 'html',
    url: 'hell.php',
    success : function(data1) {
        alert(data1);// will alert "ok"
        $('body').html(data1);
    },
});
```

Comment: So the AJAX call works fine, it's just the jQuery on the newly loaded elements does not, correct? Could you post your event handlers?

Comment: @prytsh please elaborate your question in more details.

Comment: What is _body_ and _html_? Are they IDs?

Answer (score 1):

The events you attached before $('body').html(data1) will not fire simply because the elements previously in the body will not exist anymore.

You have to re-attach the events or use [.on()](http://api.jquery.com/on/) method and attach events directly to document.

Comment: This depends. `.on()` won't always attach functionality to the loaded elements. You should "lazily" attach the functionality when the code is loaded.

Comment: Why not attach the events on the dynamically loaded html itself before loading?

Comment: Yes, it'll be better to attach events after ajax call success, but sometimes they are too many. In that case .on() should do the trick also if it's a little more "heavy".

Answer (score 0):

better use `jQuery` `live` function, when attaching event handlers.
See: http://api.jquery.com/live/

Comment: `.live()` was deprecated a while ago, and replaced by `.on()` & `.delegate()`

Answer (score 0):

First, define the functionality you want to attach to the loaded elements in a function, e.g.:

```
function attachEventsAfterAjax(){

    $('.aLoadedElement').on('click', function(){
        console.log('Yay!');
        return false;
    });

}
```

Then, after you've loaded your new content, call that function, e.g.:

```
$.ajax({
    [...],
    success: function(data){

        // Don't replace the <body> HTML, that's not a good idea
        // $('body').html(data);

        $('#container').html(data);
        
        // Now attach the functionality!
        attachEventsAfterAjax();

    }
});
```